# Intelligent replacement using given terms in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm using [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) to do symbolic calculations in Python3. My problem is to enforce a substitution of a known term a, defined as a product of x, y and z. See this minimal example:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.abc import a,x,y,z
expr=(x*y)/z**3 *(x**2*y**2-5*x*y*z+12*z**2)
print (expr) #as typed in line 3
print (expr.subs(x*y/z,a)) #only substitues the first factor to a**1/z**2
print (sp.simplify(expr)) #not any better
```

What I'd like to see is an expression of the form

```
a**3-5*a**2+12*a
```

with a=x*y/z Neither line 4 nor lines 5 or 6 do the trick. Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, for this particular example, the following idea leads to a solution, but in more generality, I don't know how to achieve the goal.

So, instead of substituting `x*y/z` as `a`, substitute equivalently `x*y` to `a*z`, and then simplify.

```
expr2 = expr.subs(x*y, a*z)
print(expr2)
print(sp.simplify(expr2))
```

Comment: This sort of trick tends to work well. Even better would be `expr.subs(x, a*z/y)`, because then it will substitute every instance of `x` (whereas an `x*y` might not be substituted if it is "hidden", like in `x*(y/z + 1)`). This trick tends to work well in general, to "rearrange" your subs equation so that you are substituting a single symbol rather than an expression, and then `simplify()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use expand first:

```
In [13]: expr.expand()
Out[13]: 
 3  3      2  2         
x ⋅y    5⋅x ⋅y    12⋅x⋅y
───── - ─────── + ──────
   3        2       z   
  z        z            

In [14]: expr.expand().subs({x * y / z: a})
Out[14]: 
 3      2       
a  - 5⋅a  + 12⋅a
```